# Convert null to string laravel and flutter

Tags: php, laravel, flutter

I have an API with data something like this:

```
{
.....
"description": null,

& here a lot of fields is null
}
```

The mobile developer(Flutter) says I can not handle null values! You should make the `null` is an empty string `""`.

So for me, it is OK, I can convert it to an empty string, *but* I'm just wondering, is this the right thing that I have to edit all things to empty! and why?

Comment: `null` is better when there's no value; your mobile developer should be able to handle this. A little baffling that they can't.

Comment: {
"description": "null",
}  and in Dart flutter code can use ?? e.g description ?? "ShowThis" ... if decription will be null text on the right side ?? will appear

Comment: @JaveedIshaq sorry I mean 'He can not' updated!

Comment: Flutter developer might be finding it difficult to convert JSON value with null to data models, If He is sure, the value type will recieve String, He can use an empty string instead of null, otherwise, backend developer should pass correct value instead of null, ... please note Dart/ Flutter can handle null value only if the type is defined .. eg String? name; .. here we are saying that String name can contain a null value ... ? question mark is added for null-safety

Comment: @sime I have answered your `empty!` question and edited the answer. Please check it out & let me know in case of further queries !

Comment: @JaveedIshaq hey, I guess the user is taking about null assertion operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The mobile developer(Flutter) says I can handle null values! You should make the null is an empty string "".

Actually, this is not fully true.

**Note** :

1. Eliminating null is not a goal. There’s nothing wrong with null. On the contrary, it’s really useful to be able to represent the absence of a value. Sometimes indicating absence is really important.
2. It is not null that is bad, it is having null go where you don’t expect it that causes problems.

---

You can definitely make some types NULL with the handy `?` null-aware operator. In your case, you can make your `String` as `String?` provided indicating absence is really important and it won't cause problems in future program flow.

The goal is to give you **control and insight** into where null can flow through your program and certainty that it can’t flow somewhere that would cause a crash.

[image: Nullable vs Non Nullable]

---

> but I'm just wondering, is this the right thing that I have to edit all things to empty! and why?

Adding `!` (null assertion operator )after any expression is equivalent to saying that "You are saying, Hey Dart ! trust me that this value will never be null"

So in short , treat it as a non-nullable type.

Comment: The problem is there is a list of API JSON data with some fields with values "null", the mobile dev says I can not handle any value with null this will cause a crash  app, you should make it an empty string!

Comment: @sime yes he cannot handle those values because as I mentioned in my answer it will cause problems in the future program flow and may cause crashes. You can simply make it empty string to avoid that

Comment: @sime it will be easier for him to handle empty strings. He can even handle null strings as I mentioned in my answer if he wants to indicate "absence"

Answer (score 0):

In your laravel installation you have the `kernel.php` file in App\Http

in that file, there is a list of middlewares shared by both API & WEB route.

Comment out the one that does the conversion from empty string to null

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class, 
//Comment out the next line 
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class, 
    ];
```

Dont forget to adapt your code if it is dependant on the `null` values somewhere else.

Comment: yeah this should work out ! But it's equivalent to what he is doing right now. Converting null to empty strings.

Comment: @anirudh that what he's asking about, why he has to do it. The answer: the middleware is doing the convertion that he needs to undo. so better remove the middleware in this case. it's not originaly in the request.